# React Native app displays white blank screen briefly before splash screen on reopening after forced stop

Tags: android, ios, react-native, splash-screen, user-experience

I've noticed that when I force stop the app on my device  and then open it again, I experience a brief white blank screen before the splash screen appears. This doesn't happen when the app is simply backgrounded and then brought to the foreground again.

I would like to know why this white blank screen is appearing and if there's any way to avoid it or reduce its duration.

I have already tried searching for solutions, but I couldn't find any specific answers addressing this issue. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can we get a [mcve] please?